# Why should /var /opt /tmp /home /boot directories be on different partitions?

Tags: partition

Why should I split these directories across multiple partitions? Performance? Security maybe?

Comment: Note that none of those reasons is mandatory or particularly significant in many contexts, and there is one significant *disadvantage* (you can't use space dynamically that way), so if you want to put everything on one partition, go right ahead.

Comment: The more usual terminology is that you partition drives and possible mount a partition on a specific directory. You certainly do not partition folders (if by that you mean directories).